# "Application request limit reached" - but there's no API Usage chart, how to solve?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph

So, as many of you already know, Facebook is struggling with an issue related to API usage limit.

I've got an old app I must use on a premium javascript plugin, then it **must work on any site domain**.

Since June the app is being constantly stopped and FB returns "*GraphAPIError: (#4) Application request limit reached*". As I read [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/169774397034403/) I should open a ticket on FB, but in the app dashboard I don't have any chart about API usage.

How can I solve this situation?

Comment: what´s the script doing?

Comment: _“How can I solve this situation?”_ - Eventually, likely only by making less requests … There is no preferred treatment for general 3rd-party apps, you need to make do with the resources available. _“but in the app dashboard I don't have any chart about API usage”_ - should be right on the first page of the app dashboard, no? Section titled “Current Application Level Rate Limit Status” ... I see that for newly created apps as well as old ones.

Comment: The API also sends certain response headers, when your app comes close to being limited - not sure if those are accessible if you use only the JS SDK(?) to make your requests. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting has details.

Comment: Sorry probably I wasn't clear enough: the app is sold and then I can't know how many times it is used. However it worked perfectly until the big June's change. I'm getting the "Application request limit reached" response on my JS API call.

Anyway this is not the point: as @CBroe suggested, I should have that chart, however this is not the case. Only my recent apps have it, old ones (from 2012) don't.

How can this be possible?